# Roscore not finding rostopic

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am configuring a whole new setup, with a new Turtleot3, a new computer, and a new wifi network. And I can't get what should simple to work...

On a Mac, Running VMware, with Ubuntu 16.04, and ROS Kinetic installed (correctly, I hope), I have the following confusing behavior. Do you see the problem?

Here are the key environment variables defined in bashrc in the VMWare Linux instance:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.64.123.200:11311
export ROS_IP=129.64.123.200
```

In a fresh shell on VMWare:

```
$ Roscore
... logging to /home/pitosalas/.ros/log/fdf2db06-860d-11e8-b1a7-000c29b28fa8/roslaunch-ubuntu-44713.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://localhost:45411/
ros_comm version 1.12.13


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [44723]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/

setting /run_id to fdf2db06-860d-11e8-b1a7-000c29b28fa8
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [44736]
started core service [/rosout]
```

#### Note regarding `localhost`

The report of ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 is what Roscore displays. In both shells we are running on the same .bashrc with  `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.64.123.200:11311` so I have to assume that Roscore noticing that the master uri env matches localhost, decides to display it as localhost.

Here's the /etc/hosts file which is all defaults as far as I can tell.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

#### printenv | grep ros

```
$ printenv | grep ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/pitosalas/bin:/home/pitosalas/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PYTHONPATH=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

#### printenv | grep ROS

```
$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.64.123.200:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/pitosalas/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_IP=129.64.123.200
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

#### Unable to communicate

Continuing, the same VMWare Linux instance,  a different shell:

```
$ rostopic list
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297195/roscore-not-finding-rostopic/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-12**:
Can you check your `hosts` file to see what the `localhost` entry maps to?

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-12**:
I've updated the original question with the hosts file.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-12**:
Can you update your question with the output of `printenv | grep ROS`?

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-12**:
Thanks for taking the time to look at this, question is updated.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-12**:
Np. Can you try it again with `ROS` capitalized? `grep` is case sensitive.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-12**:
updated. thanks!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-12**:
What happens if you manually set `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP` in each terminal?

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-07-12**:
Weird: I did

```
$ export ROS_IP=129.64.123.200
$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.64.123.200:11311
```

On both shells, and then I did

```
$ roscore
```

and nothing happened. I tried to ^c and this happened:

```
WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://129.64.123.200:11311] host is not set to this machine
```

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-07-13**:
I was able to reproduce the error you got by setting the ROS_MASTER_URI to something that I can not ping. Can you ping the IP you tried to set your as your MASTER_URI and IP ?

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2018-07-13**:
`ROS_IP` should be the ip of the computer you are using

`ROS_MASTER_URI` should be the ip of ROS_MASTER, the same as ROS_IP **only** if the computer you are using is the master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem! If we look closely at my printenv, you see that there's a ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost that is being set somewhere. By the doc, that overrides the ROS_IP I have below!! Thanks for all your time and help troubleshooting this.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2018-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0